# How to check if computations are done in DataSpell

Tags: python, dataspell

I am running the following code in DataSpell

```
some_object = function_with_very_long_computations()
```

I seem not able to find any indicators in DataSpell to confirm that line execution is completed. Especially in the case where some_object already exists and I am trying to refresh it. I can surely write something `new_variable = 3+5` and run it immediately after my main line and check when `new_variable` is populated, but this looks like an awkward solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it within a Jupyter notebook, it'll have an indication whether the cell is still running or not.

EDIT:

For Python scripts, there is a button "Show Command Queue" on the Python Console toolbar, which displays a green dot while the script is running (see screenshot).[image]
Not the most intuitive UI, but at least it's there.

Comment: Thank you, do you by any chance know anything about other mode (not Jupyter notebook)? My whole goal of using DataSpell is to get environment similar to R-studio rather than Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your comment.